# Pass variable from server-side controller to client-side to use in client-side JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, user-permissions

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I have a model that stores the owner of a list and the members that have been added. The owner and members are represented by objects. Each member object contains a field for permissions - when a member is added to a list, they have default permissions, represented by SUGGEST. An owner of a list can change a member's permissions later.

I want to pass the user's permissions when they access a list page, via a route.

**What I can't figure out:**
I need to be able to access the permissions in my client-side JavaScript, because I'll use the permissions to restrict what a user can do on any given list they own or are a member of. In my client-side JavaScript, I'm going to set a user permission variable that I check against before I run a function to make changes to the list.

**How would you handle user permissions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never restrict a user's access only using client-side javascript since the only thing the user has to do to overcome your restrictions is to edit the rendered javascript file.

You should use a templating library like Pug to only render the allowed options to a user and even after that you should do backend checks for restricted controllers.

Example: rendering the profile link only if the user is logged in.

```
// app.js
...
Router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('indexPage', {loggedIn: true});
});

// indexPage.pug
html
  head
    //- ... head stuff
    nav
      if(loggedIn)
        a.nav-item(href='/profile') Profile
      else
        a.nav-item(href='/signin') Sign In
```

Comment: I am using Pug and I'm glad you brought the security issue up. I'm using pug in much the same way you demonstrated, but actually reading what you said has given me the answer I need. I'll handle permissions on the server-side. So obvious, but thank you!